# Unable to recognize element with class which is inside foreach?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, autocomplete

I am trying autocomplete functionality here and i am stuck when i type something in textbox i expect it hits `$('.autoclass').autocomplete({ //mycode` but it doesn't hit .

**My view :**

```
<input type="text" class="autoclass"  data-bind="value:$root.email" /> // This hits --(1)

<div class="form-body" data-bind="foreach:dataArray">

<input type="text" class="autoclass"  data-bind="value:$root.email" /> //This wont --(2)

</div>
```

Then i tought there is something err ..! with my code i.e tried a change event on class `.autoclass` but same result sadly but interestingly here i tried placing same textbox outside `foreach` where both(autocomplete & change event) it works like a charm where textbox inside loop has same problem it doesn't even hit

**Change event :**

```
 $('input.autoclass').change(function () {
 //my code
});
```

As far my observation goes there are no errors in console . 
Previously i used Knockout autocomplete which is not effective in my case (i need to get updated list like jquery autocomplete everytime it hits controller when i enter).

Is there any hack around to work it in jquery for dyanamically created elements(textbox with same class)

**{EDIT}**

After suggestions i tried JqAuto plugin which works ok but small issue here .

Sample Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/1t92rf9t/) demonstrates the issue

When i select autocomplete data from textbox-1 the selected value is binded to textbox-2 and vice versa . Well as i am using `root` in my view for `value` it tends to bind like that i guess(same observable for both) . any alternate way to make this one work.

Apologies if something is unclear and let me know in case of any additional info .

Comment: It is not clear why don't you use a proper bindinghandler (https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-jqAutocomplete) for the autocomplete and why do you want to apply it manually? Your code is not wokring because it is applied before the foreach addes the elements to the DOM so jquery won't find for foreach generated textboxes.

Comment: @nemesv i haven't gone through the link previously when i tried auto-complete with binding handlers you just provided me great link i will go through that . `Your code is not working ..` ooh i see it now but any other way we can make it work .

Comment: added fiddle any suggestions are great .!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you attach an event handler with jQuery, it only applies to the elements that currently exist.  It doesn't apply the event handler to elements created later, which is likely the case with your inputs which are being controlled by knockout.

One solution is to keep track of when elements are added and attach the event handler to them then, but it's simpler to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), where you attach the event handler to some parent element that isn't being dynamically added and removed.  For example:

```
$(document).on("change", "input.autoclass", function() {

});
```

`document` can be changed to any parent of the inputs that isn't being dynamically added and removed from the document.

Comment: yes the reason you given is perfect like @nemesv mentioned . let me try that . The delegate i need to keep in my document.ready or outside to it (i have limited `$` knowledge). Thank you